# Pandas: identify consecutive numbers in a column with repeated elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry if the question is not clear, let me describe my issue in this post. I have the following dataframe:

```
        value                created_at   t_diff  flag_1
0   18.930542 2019-03-03 21:43:08-05:00 00:00:00       1
1   18.895210 2019-03-03 21:44:09-05:00 00:00:00       1
2   18.895210 2019-03-03 21:45:09-05:00 00:00:00       1
3   18.885010 2019-03-03 21:46:10-05:00 00:04:04       2
4    0.000000 2019-03-03 21:47:11-05:00 00:04:04       2
5    0.000000 2019-03-03 21:48:12-05:00 00:04:04       2
6    0.000000 2019-03-03 21:49:13-05:00 00:04:04       2
7    0.000000 2019-03-03 21:50:14-05:00 00:04:04       2
8   18.857025 2019-03-03 21:51:14-05:00 00:00:00       3
9   18.847290 2019-03-03 21:52:15-05:00 00:00:00       3
10  18.847290 2019-03-03 21:53:17-05:00 00:00:00       3
11  18.873283 2019-03-03 21:54:17-05:00 00:00:00       3
12  18.873283 2019-03-03 21:55:19-05:00 00:00:00       3
13  18.837677 2019-03-03 21:56:19-05:00 00:00:00       3
20  18.830170 2019-03-03 22:03:25-05:00 00:00:00       5
21  18.826149 2019-03-03 22:04:26-05:00 00:00:00       5
22  18.826149 2019-03-03 22:05:27-05:00 00:00:00       5
23  18.830795 2019-03-03 22:06:28-05:00 00:00:00       5
```

From the column 'flag_1', I'd like to identify the elements that, despite being repeated, form a succession of consecutive numbers. The outcome I desire is like the following

```
        value                created_at   t_diff  flag_1  flag_2
0   18.930542 2019-03-03 21:43:08-05:00 00:00:00       1       1
1   18.895210 2019-03-03 21:44:09-05:00 00:00:00       1       1
2   18.895210 2019-03-03 21:45:09-05:00 00:00:00       1       1
3   18.885010 2019-03-03 21:46:10-05:00 00:04:04       2       1
4    0.000000 2019-03-03 21:47:11-05:00 00:04:04       2       1
5    0.000000 2019-03-03 21:48:12-05:00 00:04:04       2       1
6    0.000000 2019-03-03 21:49:13-05:00 00:04:04       2       1
7    0.000000 2019-03-03 21:50:14-05:00 00:04:04       2       1
8   18.857025 2019-03-03 21:51:14-05:00 00:00:00       3       1
9   18.847290 2019-03-03 21:52:15-05:00 00:00:00       3       1
10  18.847290 2019-03-03 21:53:17-05:00 00:00:00       3       1
11  18.873283 2019-03-03 21:54:17-05:00 00:00:00       3       1
12  18.873283 2019-03-03 21:55:19-05:00 00:00:00       3       1
13  18.837677 2019-03-03 21:56:19-05:00 00:00:00       3       1
20  18.830170 2019-03-03 22:03:25-05:00 00:00:00       5       2
21  18.826149 2019-03-03 22:04:26-05:00 00:00:00       5       2
22  18.826149 2019-03-03 22:05:27-05:00 00:00:00       5       2
23  18.830795 2019-03-03 22:06:28-05:00 00:00:00       5       2
```

Column named 'flag_2' should be populated with a numeric identifier each time of these "successions" from consecutive repeated numbers occur. 1 for the first, 2 for the second, 3 for the third and so on.

I have been trying to do this indirectly, using df.flag_1.unique() and then with the help of [more-itertools](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) created a nested list which I would loop over, slicing the dataframe using [isin from Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

I'd like to know if there's a way to do all this with Pandas and without using more-itertools and the rest of my approach.

Can you help me out please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you want `flag_2` to increase if the numbers in `flag_1` increment by more than 1?

Comment: @josemz I think I get what you mean. I would've tried using df['flag_2']=df['flag_1'].diff() if it weren't for the repeated values.

Comment: `df['flag_2'] = (df.flag_1 - df.flag_1.shift(1) > 1).cumsum()+1`

Comment: @jxc This does it, thank you! 

Curious: why don't you write it as an answer? So I can upvote it there as well an mark as accepted (unless an even simpler solution comes).   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it by using `diff` and `cumsum` , logic here is continue value the different should not greater than 1 , in your example, every time it will increase by one or maintain the same (no change so the different should be 0 )

```
df.flag_1.diff().gt(1).cumsum()+1
Out[351]: 
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    1
20    2
21    2
22    2
23    2
Name: flag_1, dtype: int32
```